# Plone - Is it possible to change the workflow state of an object without needing the Modify portal content permission?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to allow a group with a role Contract Reviewer to change the state of an object without needing the 'Manage portal content' role in a particular state.

The Contract Reviewer is granted a permission: 'MyProduct: Review contract', in rolemap.xml

The 'MyProduct: Review contract' permission is required for two transitions: Approve Contract and Reject Contract.  These two transitions are available in  a 'Pending contract approval' state.

The permissions seem to work as other user groups do not see these transitions available, but the Manager and Contract Reviewer roles can see these transitions.

However, in my workflow, unless the 'Modify portal content' permission is assigned in that state, the Project Reviewer cannot see the 'Edit bar' to 'approve' or 'reject'.

Is there another permission to show the edit bar that I am missing?

Comment: You may have better luck posting Plone questions in https://community.plone.org

Comment: I figured it out.  For some reason the group assigned the Contract Reviewer role didn't have the Reviewer role.

Comment: Great! Maybe you could add that below as an answer...